# Return Json to jQuery with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have this code..

```
        Models.Person p = new testmvc.Models.Person { Firstname = "yongeks", Lastname = "ucab" };

        Models.Person p2 = new testmvc.Models.Person { Firstname = "lyn", Lastname = "torreon" };

        string q = JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(new String[] { JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(p), JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(p2) });

        Console.WriteLine(q);

        return q;
```

i need to parse this code into jquery.. using json request.. can somebody help me..

Answer (score 8):

Just use the controller's Json method to serialize the type and return a JsonResult:

```
Models.Person p2 = new testmvc.Models.Person { Firstname = "lyn", Lastname = "torreon" };
return Json( p2 );
```

Answer (score 4):

I like working with the [Newtonsoft](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) json library. it allows you greater control over the json serialization process so you can specify what to do with null values etc

e.g

```
  JsonNetResult jsonNetResult = new JsonNetResult();
  jsonNetResult.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
  jsonNetResult.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
  jsonNetResult.Data = nodes
  return jsonNetResult;
```